# Dynamic character in UE4

Tags: unreal-4

I've been creating simple characters in Blender for a while, and now I want to add dynamic details to them. I managed to make a cloak with using UE4 cloth physics.

However I have trouble with smaller things. As english isn't my primary language, I don't even know how to name this issue properly. Example of things I want to achieve:

1. Simple polygon ponytail that bounces while running
2. Edges of clothes, like shorts are loose and also move while running
3. Accessories like bracelets or dangling keys on wrists / hanging from clothes which also move a bit while walking

Is this something I do in Blender and export, or is it something I add in Unreal?
What should I look for?

EDIT:
So far I found this thanks to a comment:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/AnimDynamics/index.html

But if anyone else has suggestions, please keep them coming.

Comment: I usually see this type of reactive swinging/bouncing/dangling/wiggling on a character called "secondary motion". Here the primary movement is the character's skeletal animation, and these things react as a secondary consequence. If you're comfortable with vertex shaders, they can be a powerful way to create these effects cheaply, [as described in this talk with examples from Destiny](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022966/Animating-With). Others may be able to advise on Unreal-specitic solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. The link you provided seems very good, but it is a bit too complex for me, at least for now. But your suggestion about "secondary motion" made me find a very interesting article in 10 seconds:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/AnimDynamics/index.html

Comment: Actually, if you could write this as a post, I could choose it as a solution?